# How to remove non contiguous elements from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector `std::vector<inputInfo> inputList` and another vector `std::vector<int> selection`.
`inputInfo` is a struct that has some information stored.

The vector `selection` corresponds to positions inside `inputList` vector.

I need to remove elements from `inputList` which correspond to entries in the `selection` vector.

Comment: Sort `selection` in descending order, then iterate over it an do `inputList.erase(inputList.begin() + index)`. You can do better, but if `inputList` is small, that's basically enough. If you can't alter `selection`, make a copy of it.

Comment: I'd suggest to change `selection` to `std::vector<size_t>`. Positions can't be negative, and could be larger than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt on this removal algorithm.

Assuming the `selection` vector is sorted and using some (unavoidable ?) pointer arithmetic, this can be done in one line:

```
template <class T>
inline void erase_selected(std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<int>& selection)
{
    v.resize(std::distance(
      v.begin(),
      std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(),
         [&selection, &v](const T& item) {
            return !std::binary_search(
               selection.begin(), selection.end(),
               static_cast<int>(static_cast<const T*>(&item) - &v[0]));
         })));
}
```

This is based on an idea of Sean Parent (see this [C++ Seasoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA) video) to use `std::stable_partition` ("stable" keeps elements sorted in the output array) to move all selected items to the end of an array.

The line with pointer arithmetic

```
static_cast<int>(static_cast<const T*>(&item) - &v[0])
```

can, in principle, be replaced with STL algorithms and index-free expression

```
std::distance(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), item), std::begin(v))
```

but this way we have to spend O(n) in `std::find`.

The shortest way to remove non-contiguous elements:

```
template <class T> void erase_selected(const std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<int>& selection)
{
    std::vector<int> sorted_sel = selection;
    std::sort(sorted_sel.begin(), sorted_sel.end());

    // 1) Define checker lambda
    // 'filter' is called only once for every element,
    // all the calls respect the original order of the array
    // We manually keep track of the item which is filtered
    // and this way we can look this index in 'sorted_sel' array
    int itemIndex = 0;
    auto filter = [&itemIndex, &sorted_sel](const T& item) {
        return !std::binary_search(
                  sorted_sel.begin(),
                  sorted_sel.end(),
                  itemIndex++);
    }

    // 2) Move all 'not-selected' to the end
    auto end_of_selected = std::stable_partition(
                           v.begin(),
                           v.end(),
                           filter);

    // 3) Cut off the end of the std::vector
    v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), end_of_selected));
}
```

Original code & test

---

If for some reason the code above does not work due to strangely behaving `std::stable_partition()`, then below is a workaround (wrapping the input array values with `selected` flags.

I do not assume that `inputInfo` structure contains the `selected` flag, so I wrap all the items in the `T_withFlag` structure which keeps pointers to original items.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
std::vector<T> erase_selected(const std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<int>& selection)
{
    std::vector<int> sorted_sel = selection;
    std::sort(sorted_sel.begin(), sorted_sel.end());

    // Packed (data+flag) array
    struct T_withFlag
    {
        T_withFlag(const T* ref = nullptr, bool sel = false): src(ref), selected(sel) {}

        const T* src;
        bool selected;
    };

    std::vector<T_withFlag> v_with_flags;

    // should be like
    //      { {0, true}, {0, true}, {3, false},
    //        {0, true}, {2, false}, {4, false},
    //        {5, false}, {0, true}, {7, false} };
    //  for the input data in main()

    v_with_flags.reserve(v.size());

    // No "beautiful" way to iterate a vector
    // and keep track of element index
    // We need the index to check if it is selected
    // The check takes O(log(n)), so the loop is O(n * log(n))
    int itemIndex = 0;
    for (auto& ii: v)
        v_with_flags.emplace_back(
            T_withFlag(&ii,
                       std::binary_search(
                          sorted_sel.begin(),
                          sorted_sel.end(),
                          itemIndex++)
                       ));

    // I. (The bulk of ) Removal algorithm
    //   a) Define checker lambda
    auto filter = [](const T_withFlag& ii) { return !ii.selected; };
    //   b) Move every item marked as 'not-selected'
    //      to the end of an array
    auto end_of_selected = std::stable_partition(
                               v_with_flags.begin(),
                               v_with_flags.end(),
                               filter);
    //   c) Cut off the end of the std::vector
    v_with_flags.resize(
        std::distance(v_with_flags.begin(), end_of_selected));

    // II. Output
    std::vector<T> v_out(v_with_flags.size());
    std::transform(
               // for C++20 you can parallelize this
               // with 'std::execution::par' as first parameter
               v_with_flags.begin(),
               v_with_flags.end(),
               v_out.begin(),
               [](const T_withFlag& ii) { return *(ii.src); });
    return v_out;
}
```

The test function is

```
int main()
{
    // Obviously, I do not know the structure
    // used by the topic starter,
    // so I just declare a small structure for a test
    // The 'erase_selected' does not assume
    // this structure to be 'light-weight'
    struct inputInfo
    {
        int data;
        inputInfo(int v = 0): data(v) {}
    };

    // Source selection indices
    std::vector<int> selection { 0, 1, 3, 7 };
    // Source data array
    std::vector<inputInfo> v{ 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 7 };

    // Output array
    auto v_out = erase_selected(v, selection);

    for (auto ii : v_out)
        std::cout << ii.data << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```